# Unable to connect to remote Microsoft SQL Server from Google Colab due to SQL driver not found error

Tags: sql-server, google-colaboratory

I have SQL Server 2019 installed on a server machine, that hosts a database named 'MyDB'. On my PC I'm trying to connect to that database from Google Colab.
Initially I was using the following code block-

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'Server=0.tcp.in.ngrok.io,*****;'
                      'Database=MyDB;'
                      'Username=****;'
                      'Password=****;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
cnxn = engine.connect()
```

This raised an error-

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I found the following code snippet that people have been using to get around this error-

```
%%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

It seems to have worked even a few months back, but now this raises the following error-

> CalledProcessError: Command 'b'curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -\ncurl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list\nsudo apt-get update\nsudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17\n'' returned non-zero exit status 100.

I would be obliged if someone could help me connect to the SQL Server database by solving this issue.

Comment: just run the command manually and see what it says? perhaps the package is gone so you need to update the urls

Comment: Have you tried executing those commands individually to see which one actually fails? Depending on how "raw" the image you're starting with is you may actually need to `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends curl` before executing the rest of your commands.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that `ubuntu:16.04`/`ubuntu:xenial` aren't officially supported any more (standard support ran out in 2021) and they haven't been updated on Dockerhub in over a year. Might be time to upgrade your base image to something newer.

Comment: Yes I tried executing them individually, the last one fails-
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I don't know what image is there in Google Colab, but I can't seem to install msodbcsql17 in the Colab notebook in any possible way. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a grueling day trying to troubleshoot this error, I finally found a fix, that I believe should not only work on Google Colab but on any Ubuntu machine. As @AlwaysLearning pointed out "*ubuntu:16.04/ubuntu:xenial aren't officially supported any more (standard support ran out in 2021) and they haven't been updated on Dockerhub in over a year.*", so the previous code snippet being used everywhere has been rendered obsolete.

I observed that the issue was because, before installing msodbcsql17, it tried to install 3 other packages-

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libodbc1 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2
```

and apt failed to install them because of version conflicts between Microsoft and unixodbc. Apt tries to install both but it can't since both packages try to install the same file. This issue has been raised in multiple forums but since the issue was on the side of Microsoft, people could only provide temporary hacks up until then.

Fortunately I bumped into one of Microsoft's own page [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline) from where I found the following code snippet, and this works perfectly fine-

```
%%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
```

Comment: It would be interesting from an academic perspective to see what `lsb_release -rs` outputs - it may not even be `16.04`.

Comment: On the `unixodbc` front, Microsoft is well known for randomly clobbering the versions of `unixodbc` and `unixodbc-dev` on their package repositories. When building my own containers I install all of the dependencies from the distro's repos before I even add a reference to the Microsoft repos, e.g.: for `msodbc17` on Ubuntu 16.04 I'd... `apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl lsb-core lsb-release unixodbc-dev` before pulling down `https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list`

Comment: Yes it's 22.04 now, but if you simply replaced the 16.04 in the previous link, it still wouldn't work. But you know what? Your solution works too! You can post it as your answer or I'll just update mine.